# Use IF condition with ISNULL - Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, isnull

I am trying to calculate a formula but its not workig or i am doing it wrong (obiviously). The scenario is that i have 10 textboxes and a calculation field. I want access to apply a formula on that calculated field (total) according to the data input in those 10 fields.

e.g if the field 9 and 10 is empty then (total) will be divided by 8. Else it should be divided by 9 or ten respectivly. any help in this regard will be appreciated. thanks in advance

what i am expecting
if sub9 is null then total/8
if sub10 is null then total/9
else total/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be:

```
Final = Total / (8 + Abs(Not IsNull([Field9])) + Abs(Not IsNull([Field10])))
```

Comment: Bundle of thanks bro :) :) :) i was stuck here from last week and you code worked like a charm. just one more question. can you help me in one more VBA code? if yes i will post it in next comment.


thanks again bro :)

Comment: Great! But post a new question with your second request.

Comment: sure i will bro